# Azure Table Batch Operation element 0 in the batch returned an unexpected response code

Tags: azure, storage, azure-table-storage

I have 100 entity with same partition key and I want to update these entities to my azure storage table:

- Option 1: looping through each entity and use individual operation to execute (InsertOrReplace). It works fine, no column exceed max size (table has only 8 column with string and byte[] type).
- Option 2: looping through each entity and use a batch operation to add the InsertOrReplace operation, then execute this batch. The data of entity is the same but I got the exception that said that element 0 in the batch returned an unexpected response code, nothing more.

Anyone face the same issue?

Comment: Can you show us the code in your option 2? I can reproduce your issue but a little difference: it's "element 1" instead of "element 0" . I solved the issue now, just wanna make sure if you have the same code with mine which cause errors.

Comment: and I can generate the error starts with "element 0", because there are some unexpected characters like "\" in rowkey or partition key. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/386) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model) for more details.

Comment: Considering individual entities are getting saved without any problem, I don't think there's an issue with the data as such. One thing you might want to check is the payload size. Maximum size of all entities in a batch can be 4MB. Please check if that's not the case. Check out this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions#requirements-for-entity-group-transactions.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information on what actually happen by inspecting `ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation`